# Cant open a .docx file after overwriting it with a different encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ms-word, ansi, notepad

This is not exactly a programming question but I came to this problem while I was trying to access to a .docx document using Python.

Basically, I opened manually the .docx with notepad and I **overwrote** it with utf-8 encoding (ANSI was the default encoding). After I did this if I try to open the document I see the next message: *"We're sorry. We can´t open filename because we found a problem with its contents"*. Clicking on details you'll see *"The file it's corrupt and cannot be opened".*

It doesn't matter if I save the file with ANSI again, it won't open. Later I tried it with a new document and the same thing happened, but it also happens if I **overwrite** it with "ANSI" (even that it's the default one).

I can still open it with notepad so my question is: **Is there a way to recover my file or to convert it to a readable document?**

I've tried every single Method of the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/word/damaged-documents-in-word and none of them worked.

**Edit:** If I open **any** ms-word with notepad and I save it with **any** encoding I wont be able to open it with ms-word anymore. I don't know why but if I open the document and erase the first two letters (PK - which I believe stands for zip document) I can open the file with ms-word but it would have unreadable characters.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Word files are zip archives containing XML, which is already encoded in UTF. A zip archive is a binary format and is **not encoded**. Notepad makes a guess, but it's wrong. That's why when you reopen the Word file that you thought you saved in UTF, Notepad still thinks it's ANSI format.

Unfortunately, your file is hosed. It's not even a zip archive anymore, so you can't open it to extract the text from the XML. Best to experiment on a copy next time.

Comment: Sad news, but thank you for your answer John